# Querying extensionAttributes in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have some extensionAttributes (1-4) synced from on-prem to Azure AD using Azure AD Connect, and I want to query these using the Microsoft Graph API, but the data returned is null

As below, the Azure AD Connect tool syncs extensionAttribute1 as extension_guid_extensionAttribute1 etc..

In this example I've changed the GUID randomly

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId test.user@mydomain.com | Select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty

Key                                                            Value
---                                                            -----
odata.metadata                                                 https://graph.windows.net/ec28dcc...
odata.type                                                     Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime
employeeId
onPremisesDistinguishedName                                    CN=Test User,OU=Users - Active,DC=internal,DC=...
thumbnailPhoto@odata.mediaContentType                          image/Jpeg
userIdentities                                                 []
extension_034abf7ea2ee45317869abe74870bf20_extensionAttribute4 7119
extension_034abf7ea2ee45317869abe74870bf20_extensionAttribute3 0834717194
extension_034abf7ea2ee45317869abe74870bf20_extensionAttribute1 \\fileserver\scan\folder\Test.User
```

What I can find in the documentation is these attributes should be called onPremisesExtensionAttributes when queried via the API, but they're all null:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes)/$entity",
    "displayName": "Test User",
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute1": null,
        "extensionAttribute2": null,
        "extensionAttribute3": null,
        "extensionAttribute4": null,
        "extensionAttribute5": null,
        "extensionAttribute6": null,
        "extensionAttribute7": null,
        "extensionAttribute8": null,
        "extensionAttribute9": null,
        "extensionAttribute10": null,
        "extensionAttribute11": null,
        "extensionAttribute12": null,
        "extensionAttribute13": null,
        "extensionAttribute14": null,
        "extensionAttribute15": null
    }
}
```

Likewise, if I query the attribute name directly:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,extension_034abf7ea2ee45317869abe74870bf20_extensionAttribute1)/$entity",
    "displayName": "Test User"
}
```

I hope to be able to get the values of these extension attributes via the Microsoft Graph API, but they're blank. I know the data is in there because I can see it via the PowerShell get-AzureADUser cmdlet so I must be missing something.

This is all through the Graph Explorer, I haven't written any code yet to try and query this outside of the Graph Explorer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If your want to see all the properties of a user use the next url `/users/youruser@domain.com?$select=*` the amount of properties returned also depends on the consented scopes

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, but sadly that only returns a limited set of properties; businessPhones, displayName, givenName, jobTitle, mail, mobilePhone, officeLocation, preferredLanguage, surname, userPrincipalName and id.

Comment: What you descripe could also be an issue with the token, did you request a scope that allows all properties? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get

Comment: @Stephan Possibly scope related yeah. When I actually used the API I got the data out of the attributes, so it was either an issue with graph explorer or more likely, the scope set in the graph explorer.

Answer (score 4):

In order to see all the attributes for users other than yourself, you must be granted the `User.Read.All` permission.

In Graph Explorer, click on "modify permissions" underneath the signin button to add permissions (you may need an admin to grant them for you).

Permissions reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue when using the MSGraph Powershell SDK

(Get-MgUser -UserId "[UserObjectID]").OnPremisesExtensionAttributes did return empty values

Only when connecting to the beta endpoint it returned values.

Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

Connect-MgGraph -CertificateThumbprint "[CertThumbPrint]" -ClientId "[ClientIDAppRegistration]" -TenantId "[TenentID]"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was only an issue in the graph explorer. Using the API is fine. Spent ages stressing over this, should have just tested it in a real environment!

Comment: Can you please provide feedback to the Microsoft Graph team?

Comment: Did you use the Access Token from Graph Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mister Iks! You are right!
(Get-MgUser -UserId "[UserObjectID]").OnPremisesExtensionAttributes did return empty values
After run: Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
(Get-MgUser -UserId "[UserObjectID]").OnPremisesExtensionAttributes did return the values.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions attributes are synched through an application in Azure AD and this application is adding those attributes.

**Using the "Beta" profile in graph is not recommended for production use.** but "Beta" profile is fetching this information.

So, if you want to find those attributes name, specifically the Guid in the extension attribute you can do this.

```
$allApps = Get-AzureADApplication -All $true
$allApps | Get-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty
```

In my case the application Name pushing thoses attributes was "Tenant Schema Extension App". This is the default (I think) and I fetched my information with get-mgUser

```
$tenantSchemaExtensionsProperties =Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "Tenant Schema Extension App" 
| Get-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty 
| select -ExpandProperty Name
$properties = "DisplayName", "GivenName","Id","Mail","Surname","UserPrincipalName"
$tenantSchemaExtensionsProperties.ForEach({$properties +=$_})
get-mguser -Filter "userprincipalname eq 'MyUserPrincipalName'"  -Property $properties
```

Or you can do (for a less generic code)

```
get-mguser -Filter "userprincipalname eq 'MyUserPrincipalName'"  -Property "Id", "extension_[YourGuid]_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1"
```